# Ramda omit key and value if they both match

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an object that contains some data. I’d like to pick out certain keys and then also omit a key and value if they both match. Here’s my object:

```
const obj = {
  title: 'some title',
  description: 'some descrption',
  image: 'default_image.png'
}
```

What I’d like to do, is to extract `description` and `image`, and then omit the `image` if it has a value of `'default_image.png'`.

```
const fn = R.compose(
  // if image === 'default_image.png' then omit it
  R.pickAll(['description', 'image'])
)
```

Not sure what the best ramda function is to use for the second part of the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like

```
const fn = pipe(
  when(propEq('image', 'default_image.png'), dissoc('image')),
  pick(['description', 'image'])
);
```

[`dissoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#dissoc) returns a copy of an object with a specific key removed.  [`propEq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) tests if the given property of an object matches the value supplied.  And [`when`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) takes a predicate and a conversion function.  If the predicate matches the supplied data, the result of calling the conversion function on that data is returned, otherwise that data is returned unchanged.

Note that I chose [`pick`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick) instead of [`pickAll`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pickAll).  The only difference is that `pick` skips keys it doesn't find, `pickAll` returns them with value `undefined`.

You can see this in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20objs%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%201%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%201%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img1.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%202%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%202%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img2.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%203%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%203%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img3.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%204%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%204%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27default_image.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%205%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%205%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img5.png%27%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20when%28propEq%28%27image%27%2C%20%27default_image.png%27%29%2C%20dissoc%28%27image%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20pick%28%5B%27description%27%2C%20%27image%27%5D%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Amap%28fn%2C%20objs%29)**.

If you were always going to operate on a list instead of individual objects, you might switch from `pick` to [`project`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#project):

```
const fn = pipe(
  project(['description', 'image']),
  map(when(propEq('image', 'default_image.png'), dissoc('image')))
);

fn(objects);
```

This one is also available on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20objs%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%201%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%201%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img1.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%202%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%202%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img2.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%203%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%203%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img3.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%204%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%204%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27default_image.png%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Btitle%3A%20%27title%205%27%2C%20description%3A%20%27desc%205%27%2C%20image%3A%20%27img5.png%27%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20project%28%5B%27description%27%2C%20%27image%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28when%28propEq%28%27image%27%2C%20%27default_image.png%27%29%2C%20dissoc%28%27image%27%29%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Afn%28objs%29%3B%0A)**.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two different functions and one boolean function that checks for the field applying it with ramda's `ifElse`

```
const obj1 = {
  title: 'some title',
  description: 'some descrption',
  image: 'default_image.png'
}

const obj2 = {
  title: 'title',
  description: 'descrption',
  image: 'image.png'
}

const withImage = R.pickAll(['description', 'image']);
const withoutImage = R.pickAll(['description']);
const hasDefault = obj => obj['image'] == 'default_image.png'

const omit = R.ifElse(hasDefault, withoutImage, withImage);

console.log(omit(obj1));
console.log(omit(obj2));
```

The simplest way I could think of is using `pickBy`

```
const hasDefault = (val, key) => key == 'image' && val == 'default_image.png' ? false : true
console.log(R.pickBy(hasDefault, obj1))
console.log(R.pickBy(hasDefault, obj2))
```

Comment: The calls to `R.compose` are unnecessary.

Comment: @ScottSauyet niice! It looks way better